# How to solve problem with IMemoryCache, which is passed to another project

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, memorycache

I would like to ask you for help in solving the problem with IMemoryCache. There problem appears when i add the value to the IMemoryCache in the second project, and the value is not available in the first one.

First project code:

```
builder.Services.AddMemoryCache();
builder.Services.AddIntoMemoryCache(); //Extension from second project where i add to memory cache
```

Second project code:

```
public static class ServiceCollectionExtension
{
    public static void AddIntoMemoryCache(this IServiceCollection serviceCollection)
    {
        using var serviceProvider = serviceCollection.BuildServiceProvider();
        var memoryCacheService = serviceProvider.GetService<IMemoryCache>();

        memoryCacheService.Set(1, 1, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10)); //Values is added
    }
}
```

First project code (there is no value added in second project):

```
using var serviceProvider = builder.Services.BuildServiceProvider();
var memoryCacheService = serviceProvider.GetService<IMemoryCache>();
var values = memoryCacheService; // 0 values
```

Thanks for all answers.

*Edited:
IMemoryCacheService in first project and second has different object id.

Comment: Fixed, but problem stills exists

Comment: you're building a new `ServiceProvider` which - as the name suggests - will privde completely new services. You should pass the existing provider to your extension-method: `builder.Services.AddIntoMemoryCache(serviceProvider)`

Comment: Ok, but AddMemoryCache register IMemoryCache as singleton, so inside servicecollection we always should have same reference?

Comment: No because the `IMemoryCache` singleton is created twice, each one for the two service providers you are building. Use `GetHashCode()` on memory cache instances and compare them to see these are different objects. Singleton lifetime limits services to a single instance, but only within the same service provider.

Comment: @Prolog so is it possible, to do it in some way without passing service provider?

Comment: Yes, it is. You could try using [normal singleton](https://csharpindepth.com/articles/singleton), without service provider or memory cache. I suspect you are trying to move some information during startup from second project to first project, but at this point I can only guess, because I believe you are showing us only part of the problem you are facing. If you would add more context to the issue you are trying to solve with memory cache, maybe me and other users could propose better fitted solutions.